# How can I insert custom text text on tawk.to chat by clicking button?

Tags: javascript, php, api

[image: chat window]

Is there any way to insert custom text on tawk.to chat box by clicking button  directly without typing?

Comment: You mean send some message with js?

Comment: No,I mean adding extra button to my site and after clicking that button , I want to insert custom text in the message box provided by tawk.to api.

Comment: This cannot be done because it is not supported by their JS API. You can only trigger it to open or close.